# boost property_tree::json_parser::read_json & iostreams::filtering_streambuf

Tags: c++, json, boost, stream

Im trying to read deflated json and experiencing type conversion problems, here is the code

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
std::istringstream iss(std::ios::binary);
iss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, len);
iss.imbue( std::locale("ru_RU.CP1251") );
in.push( boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor() );
in.push( iss );

boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(in, pt); // <-- Compile error
```

Compiler says:

> src/ABPacking.cpp:48: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘read_json(boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf, std::allocator,
>   boost::iostreams::public_>&, boost::property_tree::ptree&)’

The question is how to pass **filtering_streambuf** to **read_json** without unnecessary data copying?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `read_json` expects a file or file name as the first argument and that file is then parsed into the property tree that is passed as the second argument.

Comment: @Xeo no, read_json can get std::basic_istream and std::string, see [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.json_parser_hpp), so i want to pass stream i got from filtering_streambuf

Comment: Right-o, but there is no overload that takes a stream *buffer*. Just put the buffer into an `istream` and you should be fine. `std::istream input(&in);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_json` expects either a file name or a *stream* with the JSON content. You're trying to pass a stream *buffer*, and it won't know what to do with it.

As a solution, just pass the stream buffer to an `istream` that consumes it and pass that to `read_json`:

```
std::istream input(&in_buf);
read_json(input, pt);
```