# How to parse json data from websocket_client using cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, json, parsing, websocket, cpprest-sdk

I'm connecting to a WebSocket whom always replies in JSON. I see there is an extract_string method for websocket_incoming_message however after trying numerous things with json:value it seems as though you can only construct JSON arrays on-the-fly by inserting key-value pairs one-by-one. Am I missing something here or is there a way to take the output from websocket_incoming_message and directly convert it into a json:value array?

```
 websocket_client client;

    //start socket connection to server
        try {

            std::cout << "s


    ----------



            client.connect(U("wss://XZXXXZZy.com/ws?account_id=4de3f308f2f8d3247As70228f94e0d2aAea&ws_key=reception")).wait();

        }
        catch (const std::exception&e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

            //send messages to the server

            //websocket_outgoing_message msg;
            //msg.set_pong_message();
            //std::cout << "\n...........2nd.........;";

            //std::string data = "hii";
            //client.send(msg).then([]() { 
            //  
            //  
            //  
            //  
            //  /* Successfully sent the message. */ });
            //std::cout << " Successfully sent the message.";
            //std::cout << "\n...........3rd.........;";



            //receive messages from the server



            client.receive().then([](websocket_incoming_message msg) {
                std::cout << "receiving data from socket";



                return msg.extract_string();


            }).then([](std::string body) {
                //FETCHING THE DATA FROM BODY. "TEXT/JSON"
                std::cout << "displaying the data";
                std::cout << body << std::endl;

                const json::value& v1 = body.substr;




                utility::string_t jsonval = v1.serialize();
                auto array = v1.at(U("rows")).as_array();


                for (int i = 0; i<array.size(); ++i)
                {
                    auto id = array[i].at(U("id")).as_string();
                    std::wcout << "\n" << id;
                    auto key = array[i].at(U("key")).as_string();
                    std::wcout << "\n" << key;
                    auto array2 = array[i].at(U("value")).as_array();

                    std::wcout << array2[0];
                    std::wcout << array2[1];
                }

            }



            );

            //close the connection
            client.close().then([]() {


                std::cout << "successfully close socket connction";


                /* Successfully closed the connection. */
            });



I have json response in my string body.but i dont know how to parse json data from websocket responses event. i want to display contacts from api responses.please help me.. 



MY JSON RESPONSES
--------------------------------------


.{"action":"refresh_dashboard","data":{"users_list":[{"user_id":"901e6076ff351cfc2195fb86f8438a26","extensions":["1002"],"name":"Karthik M"},{"user_id":"cc3f94ecc14ee9c55670dcde9adc1887","extensions":["1006"],"name":"Rounak S Kiran"},{"user_id":"6c29ebdb34e1761fdf9423c573087979","extensions":["1003"],"name":"Amar Nath"},{"user_id":"74d5b5a9aca1faa4c2f217ce87b621d8","extensions":["1008"],"name":"Robin Raju"},{"user_id":"a7ad7e73bf93ea83c8efdc1723cba198","extensions":["1007"],"name":"Arshad Arif"},{"user_id":"b55146df593ec8d09e5fe12a8a4c1108","extensions":["1001"],"name":"Rahib Rasheed"},{"user_id":"3258f7ae4ae1db60435cbcf583f64a89","extensions":["1009"],"name":"Test User"},{"user_id":"90bc84e5e8a3427fe35e99bd4386de95","extensions":["1010"],"name":"Prince T"},{"user_id":"b501ef5b270a196afc0eed557ca74237","extensions":["1005","+17325951060"],"name":"Jineed AJ"},{"user_id":"1422af351e06adeab2de92f5a633a444","extensions":["1004"],"name":"Ashok PA"}],"busy_users":[],"reg_users":[{"user_id":"cc3f94ecc14ee9c55670dcde9adc1887","status":"registered"},{"user_id":"901e6076ff351cfc2195fb86f8438a26","status":"registered"},{"user_id":"1422af351e06adeab2de92f5a633a444","status":"registered"},{"user_id":"3258f7ae4ae1db60435cbcf583f64a89","status":"registered"},{"user_id":"b55146df593ec8d09e5fe12a8a4c1108","status":"registered"},{"user_id":"6c29ebdb34e1761fdf9423c573087979","status":"registered"}],"contacts":[{"owner_id":"cc3f94ecc14ee9c55670dcde9adc1887","status":"ready"},{"owner_id":"901e6076ff351cfc2195fb86f8438a26","status":"ready"},{"owner_id":"1422af351e06adeab2de92f5a633a444","status":"ready"},{"owner_id":"3258f7ae4ae1db60435cbcf583f64a89","status":"ready"},{"owner_id":"b55146df593ec8d09e5fe12a8a4c1108","status":"ready"},{"owner_id":"6c29ebdb34e1761fdf9423c573087979","status":"ready"}]}}
```

Comment: I want the extension,account name and status from that responses

Comment: anyone working in websocket client using cpprestsdk packages please help me.

Comment: my codes have error.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1102603/Accessing-JSON-Data-with-Cplusplus

Comment: i am working on the above links.

Comment: i got the response as json  in websocket_incoming_message event is string format.so i cant serialize .please help me

Comment: the problem is that my base class method return only string data.i want to convert my json data from string to json object and parse the data from the object. 
_ASYNCRTIMP pplx::task<std::string> web::websockets::client::websocket_incoming_message::extract_string () const

Comment: Extracts the body of the incoming message as a string value, String containing body of the message.

Comment: json cpp packages is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the complete solution .please try to use boost pacakges from nuget. The documentation will help you to parse the json data from string. I think jsoncpp is not an updated packages available in the nuget.so please try boost packages available in the nuget.

### MYJSON STRING

{"action":"refresh_dashboard","data":{"users_list":[{"user_id":"901e6076ff351cfc2195fb86f8438a26","extensions":["1002"],"name":"Karthik M"},{"user_id":"7d617ef5b2390d081d901b0d5cd108eb","extensions":["1015"],"name":"Synway User2"},{"user_id":"c8f667f7d663e81f6e7fa34b9296f067","extensions":["1012"],"name":"Rahib Video"},{"user_id":"cc3f94ecc14ee9c55670dcde9adc1887","extensions":["1006"],"name":"Rounak S Kiran"},{"user_id":"6c29ebdb34e1761fdf9423c573087979","extensions":["1003"],"name":"Amar Nath"},{"user_id":"8e15c2d95d4325cb07f0750846966be8","extensions":["1011"],"name":"TLS User"},{"user_id":"2fc4142bdacf83c1957bda0ad9d50e3d","extensions":["1014"],"name":"Synway  User1"},{"user_id":"74d5b5a9aca1faa4c2f217ce87b621d8","extensions":["1008"],"name":"Robin Raju"},{"user_id":"a7ad7e73bf93ea83c8efdc1723cba198","extensions":["1007"],"name":"Arshad Arif"},{"user_id":"b55146df593ec8d09e5fe12a8a4c1108","extensions":["1001"],"name":"Rahib Rasheed"},{"user_id":"391391de005a8f5403c7b5591f462ea1","extensions":["1013"],"name":"Sangeeth J"},{"user_id":"3258f7ae4ae1db60435cbcf583f64a89","extensions":["1009"],"name":"Aby TL"},{"user_id":"90bc84e5e8a3427fe35e99bd4386de95","extensions":["1010"],"name":"Prince T"},{"user_id":"b501ef5b270a196afc0eed557ca74237","extensions":["1005"],"name":"Jineed AJ"},{"user_id":"1422af351e06adeab2de92f5a633a444","extensions":["1004"],"name":"Ashok PA"}],"busy_users":[],"reg_users":[{"user_id":"901e6076ff351cfc2195fb86f8438a26","status":"registered"},{"user_id":"6c29ebdb34e1761fdf9423c573087979","status":"registered"}],"contacts":[{"owner_id":"901e6076ff351cfc2195fb86f8438a26","status":"ready"},{"owner_id":"6c29ebdb34e1761fdf9423c573087979","status":"ready"}]}}

### CODES

```
client.receive().then([](websocket_incoming_message msg) {
            std::cout << "receiving data from socket";

            // msg.message_type();
            return msg.extract_string();
            //1..i have one string
            //cout<<"\n///////////test"<< msg.extract_string().get().c_str();
            //  // 2.convert to json array
            //json::value::parse(   ::to_string_t(msg.extract_string().get()))
            //

        }).then([](std::string body) {

            //std::cout << "displaying the data";
            std::cout << body << std::endl;


            std::string ss = body;
            ptree pt;
            std::istringstream is(ss);
            read_json(is, pt);

            std::cout <<"\n 1st"<< "action:     " << pt.get<std::string>("action") << "\n";
            std::cout <<"\n 2nd"<< "data: " << pt.get<std::string>("data") << "\n";
            std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------";
            for (auto& e : pt.get_child("data.users_list")) {
            std::cout << "\n" << "users id " << e.second.get<std::string>("user_id") << "\n";


            }
        });
```

### useful resources

1. [Parse JSON array as std::string with Boost ptree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345401/parse-json-array-as-stdstring-with-boost-ptree)
2. [C++ boost parse dynamically generated json string (not a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537637/c-boost-parse-dynamically-generated-json-string-not-a-file/21537818)